# Looking for dataset for sentiment analysis that consists of sentences with slang words

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

I am developing a machine learning model to predict the sentiment polarity of customers' comments about some product.

Currently, I use the pretrained [twitter-roberta-base-sentiment](https://huggingface.co/cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment) as the base model.

It is works well most of the time except when predicting text contains slang words.

For example, it predict "The product is idiot proof." wrongly as Negative.

So, I want to add some labeled example sentences contains slang words into the training dataset in order to improve the model's performance at sentences contains slang.

For example:

```json
[
{"doc":"I am having a blast with this game.", "sentiment": "Postive"},
{"doc":"This game is like pigeon chess", "sentiment": "Negative"},
...
]
```

I found [SlangSD](http://liangwu.me/slangsd/), a sentiment lexicon of slang words. For my project, it has 2 drawback as a training dataset.

1. it has only words, not sentences in each entry;
2. it contains not only slang words but also many ordinary words, such as "have","project","dictionary",etc.

Comment: you're asking for recommendations. this is off-topic. please review [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what degree of slang you are targetting, but by intersecting SlangSD with a common English dictionary you might get a list of *true* slang terms.

Then, scraping a movie/game/forum website and selecting only the comments/posts with terms within your new slang list could do the trick I believe (giving you a set of sentences with slang terms). For the label, it would be imperfect, but quite viable I believe, to put the same label as the SlangSD word in the sentence.